# Error when using OpenTextFile in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to append a text file from an `aspx` page. I can overwrite the file using the `CreateTextFile` method with no problems, but when I try to use `OpenTextFile` I get:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A0036 (CTL_E_BADFILEMODE)

Source Error:

```
Line 7:      fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Line 8:      f=fs.OpenTextFile("E:\(username)\test.txt",1,True,0)
Line 9:      f.WriteLine("testfirst")
Line 10:     f.WriteLine("testsecond")
Line 11:     f.close
```

Source File: `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\asptest\write_text.aspx    Line: 10`

The code that gives me this error:

```
<%@ Debug="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
    <%
    dim fs,f
    fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    f=fs.OpenTextFile("E:\(username)\test.txt",1,True,0)
    f.WriteLine("testfirst")
    f.WriteLine("testsecond")
    f.close
    f=nothing
    fs=nothing
    %>
</body>
</html>]
```

The code that works:

```
<%@ Debug="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
    <%
    dim fs,f
    fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    f=fs.CreateTextFile("E:\(username)\test.txt",True)
    f.WriteLine("testfirst")
    f.WriteLine("testsecond")
    f.close
    f=nothing
    fs=nothing
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may be using a more recent version of FileSystemObject.  Check here for your parameters - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198742.aspx

Comment: One additional comment, this code will not scale.  One you have more than 1 request to this page you'll run into file locking issues and overwritten data as multiple threads attempt to create/open/write to that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example you´re just opening the file in read mode by passing the parameter 1 in f=fs.OpenTextFile("E:(username)\test.txt",1,True,0)

To have write access you would have to pass the parameter value 2 for write-, or 8 for append-access

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/314cz14s(v=vs.84).aspx

But why are you using the objects from the Scripting namespace rather than the more common and convenient classes from System.IO?